# get gmail contacts images

Tags: c#, google-api

I am trying to get google contact image from gmail, using `google api 3`.

I have used the code below to read the stream to get the photo:

```
public static void DownloadPhoto(ContactsRequest cr, Contact entry)
    {
        string filename = "c:\\gcontacts\\" + entry.GetHashCode() + ".jpg";

        Stream photoStream = cr.GetPhoto(entry);
        FileStream outStream = File.OpenWrite(filename);

        try
        {                
            byte[] buffer = new byte[photoStream.Length];

            photoStream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)photoStream.Length);
            outStream.Write(buffer, 0, (int)photoStream.Length);

            photoStream.Close();
            outStream.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

I am getting the below error:

`Content not modified`.

https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/myemail/610f985888b0911.

I use this function to call the service

```
public static void PrintAllContacts(ContactsRequest cr)
    {
        Feed<Contact> f = cr.GetContacts();
        foreach (Contact entry in f.Entries)
        {
            if (entry.Name.FullName != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(entry.Name.FullName);
                Console.WriteLine(entry.PhotoUri.AbsoluteUri);

                DownloadPhoto(cr, entry);
            }
        }
    }
```

and this is the request

```
RequestSettings rsLoginInfo = new RequestSettings("appname", "@gmail.com", "pass");
        rsLoginInfo.AutoPaging = true;
        ContactsRequest cRequest = new ContactsRequest(rsLoginInfo);
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
cr.GetPhoto(entry)
```

use

```
cr.Service.Query(entry.PhotoUri);
```

Answer (score 0):

It says there is a problem in the request. You should check where you make the request and share it with us, you didn't post that part in your question.

You can find the documentation here: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#retrieving_a_contacts_photo

Comment: I get the contacts the problem is that i dont get the images.